Restricting Public Access to Server IP while Using nginx-proxy-manager for Domain Exposure
I'm using nginx-proxy-manager to expose my domain, such as https://odoo.domain.com. However, I'm also able to access the same server via its IP address. How can I block public access to the server's IP address?
My setup:

I'm running odoo standtalone not dockerized it's open on port eg: 1.1.1.378079
proxy-manager is running with docker container on port :81
proxy-manager redirect's domain to odoo, but I also can I access it through ip, how can I block access ip address directly.


You can ensure the following configuration parameters are added to your Odoo config file:
http_interface = 127.0.0.1


after adding this parameter I get: 502 Bad Gateway, not sure why

Try change the 127.0.0.1 to your internal IP address instead

I found that this is known issue with, nginx-proxy-manager it's not resolved: https://github.com/NginxProxyManager/nginx-proxy-manager/issues/259
Need to specify docker ip 172.17.0.1, but it's not specified if it's gonna change in future
